# How to use variables (for performance and maintenance) in inline SELECT SQL command in DB2?

Tags: sql, variables, db2

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a, very_costly_function(b), another_fn(very_costly_function(b)) from X
```

and you can notice that very_costly_function(b) is used twice, therefore if it could be set a variable like this would be nice:

```
SET FOR EACH ROW: Z = very_costly_function(b)
SELECT a, Z, another_fn(Z) from X
```

Comment: If `very_costly_function(...)` is marked `DETERMINISTIC`, the optimizer will probably be running it a single time only, for you.  You need to check the explain plan to see if it's actually being run multiple times - SQL isn't a procedural language, execution patterns aren't necessarily what you expect: for instance, there's no such thing as strict short-circuit logic when dealing with conditions in `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a, fn_b, another_fn(fn_b) AS a_fn_b
  FROM (SELECT a, very_costly_function(b) AS fn_b
          FROM x)
```

This would save the overhead for you.
Putting values into a variable and using it again can become a bit cumbersome for a compiler, you cannot, a lot of times, directly use such a query in your front-end or other higher-tier programs. If one single query does the job, use it!

Answer (score 1):

Insert a, and very_costly_function(b) into a temp table.  Then select a, the function result, and the other function (function result) from the temp table.